# Graficar Solo Eje X Matplotlib

Tags: python, lista, matplotlib

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Deseo graficar Solo Eje X en Matplotlib.

Tengo una lista `x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` y quiero dibujar solo el eje x con ese rango de valores. No necesito un eje vertical, solo el horizontal. Como ejemplo, añado una imagen.

Ojala alguien pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ocultar un eje puedes usar el método [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_visible`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_visible.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_visible). Si también quieres eliminar las líneas que delimitan el área de datos puedes usar `matplotlib.spines.Spine.set_visible()`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



ax = plt.subplot(111)


ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.set_yticklabels(())
ax.set_xlim([-5, 25])
ax.set_xticks(range(0, 25, 5))

ax.set_xlabel('Latitude')

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]